# SAS, change font size in the put statement

Tags: sas, put

```
data _NULL_;
    file print;
    if e then put 'No observations';
    set TableA end=e;
    put 'here is the table A';
    stop;
run;
```

How do I change font size and color for the quotes in the put statement?

Comment: Where are you directing PRINT?  If you are just using standard LISTING output then you don't, since that is just a plain text file.

Comment: I will output them as a pdf file finally .

Comment: So what have you read about using ODS with data \_null_ steps and PUT statements?

Comment: I don't think you can with PUT statements. Look into PROC ODS TEXT or PROC REPORT or PRINT instead. Your code will work if your data set has 0 observations but not if it doesn't exist at all. For this type of conditional logic, usually macros are used instead.

Comment: I will read table A, sometime it is empty, sometimes it include rows of obs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you might want to use graphics options on a title statement.

However, ODS output can be modified with inline styling directives introduced via the `escapechar`.

```
ods pdf file='want.pdf';

ods escapechar = '^';

* standard options for title statement;
title color=white bcolor=blue bold italic height=36pt "Title for want";

data _null_;
  file print;
  put '^{style [fontsize=24pt color=Red]Hi}';  * inline styling;
run;

ods pdf close;
```